# Proof Verification: $\sin x$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

Proof: let $f(x)=\sin{x}$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Choose $\delta := \epsilon$, then for $x,u \in \mathbb{R}$, $|x-u|<\delta$

$$\lvert f(x)-f(u)\rvert = \lvert\sin{x} - \sin{u}\rvert = \left\lvert 2\cos{\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)}\sin{\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)}\right\rvert<2\left\lvert\sin{\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)}\right\rvert<2\left\lvert \frac{x-y}{2}\right\rvert$$
$$=\lvert x-y\rvert <\delta=\epsilon.$$

Can anyone please verify this proof? Thank you.

Comment: Looks fine. The theorem that if the derivative of $f$ is bounded then $f$ is uniformly continuous would be another way to prove it (this method helps if you get a harder function in future where there isn't a nice addition formula trick). Even if you aren't allowed to assume this theorem it's very simple to prove using the mean value theorem.

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely jot this down for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost perfect. The only slight problem lies in the inequality$$\left|2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)\right|<2\left|\sin\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)\right|.$$It should have been $\leqslant$ and not $<$.

Comment: The same for next one: $\lvert \sin x \rvert \le \lvert x \rvert$.

Comment: @Gibbs Yes, indeed.